# shall I use speak or say in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, usage

from where you get that quote, you use to speak during the class? Is  this sentence grammatically correct? or we use say or. said instead of speak?

Comment: Please explain the idea you have in mind. So far it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I also don't understand what you are asking. But note that "say" takes a direct object (the thing said) whereas "speak" normally does not take an object. (In formal or archaic English it can take a an object as in "He spoke the words that sealed their fate", but in everyday English, it is used intransitiely.) So if, as I think, you are wanting to talk about a quote that somebody is uttering, you need "say", not "speak".